# cause of pulseaudio file collisions in "nixos-rebuild switch"?

Tags: nixos

when I run nixos-rebuild switch, I get a bunch of messages about file collisions, for example

```
collision between `/nix/store/ngxigb4f3h819wslwfpg7gjb236911fg-pulseaudio-5.0/share/man/man1/pacmd.1.gz' and `/nix/store/bbdqbi3070jppr5rpydqyjsn3rb2xj8w-pulseaudio-5.0/share/man/man1/pacmd.1.gz' at /nix/store/9z6d76pz8rr7gci2n3igh5dqi7ac5xqj-builder.pl line 69.
```

they all appear to involve pulseaudio. Does this mean that I somehow have two pulseaudio packages installed? My /etc/nixos/configuration.nix has `hardware.pulseaudio.enable = true;` but doesn't reference pulseaudio in any other way.

Possibly it is somehow a conflict between the currently-running pulseaudio and the one post-configuration switch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collisions happen if two packages install the same file. If you're using unstable channel this issue was fixed for pulseaudio 4 days ago:https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/pull/4683